# Mysql numbered rows in group

Tags: mysql

I have table

```
    users|visits
    --------------
    user1|visit1
    user1|visit2
    user1|visit3
    user2|visit1
    user2|visit2
```

I want to get numbered rows in any group. How i can do this?

```
users|visits|visit number
-----------------------
user1|visit1|1
user1|visit2|2
user1|visit3|3
user2|visit1|1
user2|visit2|2
```

Comment: perhaps `replace(visits,'visit','') as visit_number`

Comment: @Nikolay : will the visit number grouped by users or visits or both?

Comment: in any user im need numbered visits

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :

```
SELECT 
users, visits, count(*)  as `visit number`
FROM tableName group by visits,users
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have provide about your problem i can imagine that you have records something like this

```
users|visits
------------
user1|visit1
user1|visit2
user1|visit1
user1|visit3
```

And you want to get

```
users|visits|visit number
-------------------------
user1|visit1|2
user1|visit2|1
user1|visit3|1
```

To do that use query like this

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT a.users, 
a.visits, 
(select count(*) from tableName b where b.users = a.users and b.visits = a.visits) as `visit number`
FROM tableName  a
```